# keep script running while screen is locked for a long time

Tags: ubuntu, php, ftp

I have a script that is running on my computer. The script is written in PHP under my XAMP server. It actually is reading some files from a remote FTP server and after processing them writes them back to the same Server. The total estimated time for finishing the process seems to be around 48 hours.

I really need to know if I lock my screen and leave my desk for around two days (a couple hours after the estimated finish time of the process), does the system stall the processes or turn it idle or etc!?!

I just hope my PC does not get disconnected from to the FTP server by no means! or if it does (based on some configurations), What do I need to do to keep the execution of my PHP script last until finished completely?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your system is up, the script will keep running, it will not stop as long as you don't log out of the system. Locking your screen will not stop the script.

Comment: What power saving option would you want to turn off?

Comment: Locking screens has stopped code execution for me, with lightdm (instantly upon locking), but not with xscreensaver previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gnu/screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen) for this purpose. Invoke screen and start your script. Detach screen after invoking your script and it will run as long as the system is on. Attach the screen back to terminal when you need to get back to the running script. Google should pull up screen tutorials and cheatsheets to get you started.

Comment: tmux or byobu is preferable for performance reasons. tmux is also more active compared to screen

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference comparing performance?

Comment: Tmux vs Screen Performance
http://jon.endpoint.com/utosc-2012/screen-vs-tmux-faceoff.html#slide9 and also this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxTse5Elq8s&t=4m13s

It's not just performance, tmux has more features.